# summary of converted and churned customers from time series dataframe

Tags: pandas, time-series, pandas-groupby, analytics, summary

I have similar to the below dataframe and I would like to create a few summary stats around the behaviour of customers over time

```
pd.DataFrame([
['id1','23/5/2019','not_emailed']
,['id1','24/5/2019','not_emailed']
,['id1','25/5/2019','emailed']
,['id1','26/5/2019','emailed']
,['id1','27/5/2019','emailed']
,['id1','28/5/2019','emailed']
,['id1','29/5/2019','emailed']
,['id1','30/5/2019','emailed']
,['id1','31/5/2019','emailed']
,['id1','1/6/2019','emailed']
,['id1','2/6/2019','emailed']

,['id2','23/5/2019','not_emailed']
,['id2','24/5/2019','not_emailed']
,['id2','25/5/2019','emailed']
,['id2','26/5/2019','emailed']
,['id2','27/5/2019','emailed']

,['id3','29/5/2019','not_emailed']
,['id3','30/5/2019','emailed']
,['id3','31/5/2019','emailed']
,['id3','1/6/2019','emailed']
,['id3','2/6/2019','emailed']

 ,['id4','29/5/2019','not_emailed']
 ,['id4','30/5/2019','emailed']
 ,['id4','31/5/2019','emailed']
 ,['id4','1/6/2019','emailed']
 ,['id4','2/6/2019','emailed']    
,['id4','2/7/2019','emailed']    
,['id4','3/7/2019','emailed']
,['id4','4/7/2019','emailed'] 
 ],columns=['id','date','status'])
```

The main scenarios that could be observed in this data set are:

id1 emailed on 25th but not converted

id2 emailed on 27th and converted on 28th because we dont see any more logs for this id

id3 emailed on 30th and converted on 3rd because we dont see any more logs for this id

id4 emailed on 30th and converted on 3rd but churned againon the 2nd

I would like to get a summary of that information per day

How many emailed, how many converted, how many churned that had previously converted

A desired potential output could be:

```
        pd.DataFrame([
        ['29/5/2019',10,3,1] ,
        ['30/5/2019',10,2,1] 
        ],columns=['date','emailed_total','converted_total','churned_total']
        )
```

Not that numbers above are random and don't reflect the stats of the first dataset shared

My approaches so far:

1)
partially solves the problem:
find first day of emailed
calculate days passed since first
group by the elapsed days and aggregate
works but not for churn customers

2)
loop through dates 
 filter out unique ids emailed
  loop through dates in the future and calculate the differences between sets
  does the job but not very clean and pythonic

Comment: In the desired output data frame with 'emailed_total', 'converted_total' and 'churned_total'.It is necessary to clarify the aggregation conditions for columns respectively. There are only two types of statuses in the data presented.

Comment: which of the three is not clear how it should be aggregated? "emailed_total": everyone emailed that day, "converted_total": everyone that was emailed before but is absent that day, "churned_total": was emailed before, converted at a previous day but they are back on list.

Comment: 'churned_total' to return to the list, what does this mean? Can you elaborate on the relationship between the total name and status? I am not a native speaker.

Comment: Right, so if the customer has churned it would appear on my data every day. if a customer has converted it would stop appearing on the data but if he churn again it would start re-appearing the data set. In the example scenario of id4: Customer emailed on 30/05/2020 and converted on the 03/06/2020 because there is no recored of that date for id4 on my data. They reappeared on the 02/07/2020 because they churned again.

Comment: What is the status of 'churned_total'? You can't count them if they have no status. Does your description refer to the number of days that were cancelled? I'm not sure more and more.

Answer (score 2):

I have written the code to answer your question as I understand it at the moment. But as I commented, the status regarding churning has been fluffed up, so there are only two different totals. It is not done. The name of the column is not the name you want either.

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
df2 = df.groupby(['date','status']).agg('count').unstack().fillna(0)
df2.columns = df2.columns.droplevel()
df2 = df2.rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index()
df2.sort_index(ascending=True, inplace=True)

df
    date    emailed     not_emailed
0   2019-05-23  0.0     2.0
1   2019-05-24  0.0     2.0
2   2019-05-25  2.0     0.0
3   2019-05-26  2.0     0.0
4   2019-05-27  2.0     0.0
5   2019-05-28  1.0     0.0
6   2019-05-29  1.0     2.0
7   2019-05-30  3.0     0.0
8   2019-05-31  3.0     0.0
9   2019-06-01  3.0     0.0
10  2019-06-02  3.0     0.0
11  2019-07-02  1.0     0.0
12  2019-07-03  1.0     0.0
13  2019-07-04  1.0     0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your request i made some insight about your data, time to conversion and unconverted id time.
I hope it helps

```
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'],infer_datetime_format=True)
df.sort_values(by='date',inplace=True)
dates=df['date'].unique()
ids=df['id'].unique()
df=df.set_index(['id','date'])

out=pd.DataFrame(index=dates)
for i, new_df in df.groupby(level=0):
    new_df=new_df.droplevel(0)
    new_df=new_df.rename(columns={'status':i})
    out=out.merge(new_df, how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True)
    

not_converted=out[out.columns[out.iloc[-1,:]=='emailed']]
converted=out[out.columns[out.iloc[-1,:].isnull()]]

start_mailing_date_NC=(not_converted=='emailed').cumsum().idxmin() #not converted id metrics

delta_NC=(dates[-1]-start_mailing_date_NC) #dates[-1] could be changed to actual date
print("Days from first mail unconverted by id: ")
print(delta_NC.to_string())
print(' Mean Days not converted: %s'%(delta_NC.mean()))
print( '\n')



start_mailing_date=(converted=='emailed').cumsum().idxmin() #converted id metrics
conversion_mailing_date=(converted=='emailed').cumsum().idxmax()#converted id metrics
delta=(conversion_mailing_date-start_mailing_date)
print("Days to conversion by id: ")
print(delta.to_string())
print(' Mean Days to conversion: %s'%(delta.mean()))
```

output:

```
Days from first mail unconverted by id: 
id4   42 days
 Mean Days not converted: 42 days 00:00:00


Days to conversion by id: 
id1   10 days
id2    4 days
id3   10 days
 Mean Days to conversion: 8 days 00:00:00
```